# I cannot connect with the server ngnix: Unable to connect

Tags: nginx

I dont get any error message in

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

I make sudo service nginx restart OK

My code in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is => https://codeshare.io/q9Nr3

My code in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` is => https://codeshare.io/Rm7wP

When I executed my code in nginx -s reload

`miguel@127:/$ nginx -s reload
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/01/29 21:02:32 [warn] 3471#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2016/01/29 21:02:32 [notice] 3471#0: signal process started
2016/01/29 21:02:32 [alert] 3471#0: kill(1154, 1) failed (1: Operation not permitted)`

I put in my terminal sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx, but I dont get permissions

Comment: Could you please add more information about nginx settings?

Comment: Yes I added extra information

Comment: Who is the owner of `/var/log/nginx` and its nested files?